# Send me a notification (such as email) whenever my webcam detects some activity

Tags: windows, webcam, video-surveillance

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows that can send me a notification (such as email)
whenever it detects some activity on my webcam (e.g., someone enters the room where my computer is located). Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are good amount of software. here are two examples:

[TinCam](https://download.cnet.com/TinCam/3000-2348_4-10207365.html) - free, can grab frame and send it to mail

[EyeLine](https://www.nchsoftware.com/surveillance/index.html) - grab video, frame, send mails and so on. Cost ~50USD for single camera, home usage

Answer (score 1):

Reddit user [ExpertBoat](https://www.reddit.com/user/ExpertBoat) [pointed](https://redd.it/ovylcw) me to the program [contacam](https://www.contaware.com/contacam.html):

> - Supported from Windows Vista up to Windows 10
> - This Video Surveillance and Live Webcam software for Windows is extremely easy on system resources, and does not contain unnecessary bloat.
> - Motion detection actions like sending email with attached movement file or running any external program
> - All the software from Contaware.com are Donationware, it is requested to donate $10 USD per installation to cover the costs. Software and web site are completely FREE FROM ADS. The source code is published under the terms of the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE.

Comment: Thanks Franck.  Can you add to your answer whether the application is gratis or commercial?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thanks, good idea, done

Comment: Thank you Franck, and thanks for posting here after you found a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

[iSpy](https://www.ispyconnect.com/) has been a long time player in this area.
I believe they have all of the feature-set you're asking for.